# Custom TypeIdResolver in spring boot application doesn't get called

Tags: spring, boot, jackson-databind

I have two applications communicating over RabbitMQ. Up to now, application A has been sending messages to application B through several queues. The new request is to replace these queues with only one queue.
I cannot touch application A, only application B. The messages coming in have

```
__TypeID__
```

in header with the application A Java class in it. In order to process incoming messages I need to resolve their type according to the value of the field in the payload, **not header**.

I have tried to achieve this by defining my TypeIdResolver class, but it seems that my typeIdResolver never gets called.
Here is the code:

```
@Data
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CUSTOM,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "operationType")
@JsonTypeIdResolver(SpaTypeIdResolver.class)
public abstract class CaAbstractMessage {
  @NotNull(message = "operationType must not be null")
  private String operationType;
}

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public final class SpaCostUnitMessage extends CaAbstractMessage {
// some additional fields
}

public class SpaTypeIdResolver extends TypeIdResolverBase {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpaTypeIdResolver.class);
    private static List<String> COST_UNIT_TYPES =
            Arrays.asList(
                   // list of values);

    private static String JOB_START = "job.start";

    private JavaType superType;

    @Override
    public void init(JavaType baseType) {
        superType = baseType;
    }

    @Override
    public String idFromValue(Object value) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String idFromValueAndType(Object value, Class<?> suggestedType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonTypeInfo.Id getMechanism() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public JavaType typeFromId(DatabindContext context, String id) throws IOException {

        logger.info("In typeFromId");
        Class<?> subType = null;

        if (id.equalsIgnoreCase(JOB_START)) {
            subType = CaJobStartMessage.class;
        } else if (COST_UNIT_TYPES.contains(id)) {
            subType = SpaCostUnitMessage.class;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected incoming SPA operationType " +  id);
        }
        logger.info("Out typeFromId {}", subType);
        return context.constructSpecializedType(superType, subType);
    }
}

// the relevant configuration class methods:

 @Bean
  public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter() {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
  }

  @Bean
  public TopicExchange exchange() {
    return new TopicExchange(exchange);
  }
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: x.y.SpaObjectOutgoingMessage from [Module "deployment.a.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at deployment.b.war//org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284)
    at deployment.b.war//org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:185)
```

and the relevant message:

```
(Body:'[B@23da4855(byte[242])' MessageProperties [headers={__TypeId__=a.SpaObjectOutgoingMessage}, contentType=application/json, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=myExchange, receivedRoutingKey=routingkey, deliveryTag=2, consumerTag=amq.ctag-V-nu0nqxflc0TQATwQV2cA, consumerQueue=myQueue])
```

I would expect that the @JsonTypeIdResolver annotation takes care of properly wiring the typeIdResolver, but it seems I am wrong.